# What's the one word for a person who generalizes everything?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, adjectives, vocabulary

I am searching for a word that qualifies a person as someone who makes sweeping generalizations on almost everything and tends to stereotype people.
He picks up one trait of a person (something which is dominant) and every other person with a similar trait becomes just a prototype of it. He fails to elicit difference in the other aspects of their character and in understanding them in a more detailed manner.

Comment: A poet, perhaps?

Comment: Presumptuous? Judgemental?

Comment: A **manager**? :) I don't think there is a single word to describe such people, I can only offer you a phrase: quick to jump to conclusions.

Comment: If I had two words to work with, I would use _categorical thinker_, since the primary activity of generalizing is to distribute specific instances of action or behavior into broader categories with identifiable compartment names, the better to prevent individual cases from having to be dealt with as unique instances.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer would be:

> - [Prejudiced](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/prejudiced): having an unreasonable dislike of or preference for somebody/something, especially based on their race, religion, sex, etc.
>
> Synonyms: narrow-minded, bigoted, intolerant
>
> - [Biased](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/biased?q=biased): having a tendency to show favour towards or against one group of people or one opinion for personal reasons; making unfair judgements.

Answer (score 0):

What about generalisor to describe someone who generalises?

Comment: Could you please give a little background as to why this would be a good word?

Answer (score 0):

Generalizator --> someone who generalizes
Terminator --> someone who terminates
Generator --> someone who generates

Short sighted or narrow minded would maybe come to mind. More the former than the latter.

Answer (score 0):

How about a universalizer?  Those who universalize typically make sweeping generalizations.